# Removing prefix before '.' (dot)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

For a variable, let's say

```
varCode = kvnownananna.ThisistheStringRequired.iobabvoabnv
```

I need to remove the prefix before `.` (dot) & remove the suffix after second `.` (dot)

Need to fetch only "`ThisistheStringRequired`".

How can we do it in xsl-fo template ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="newVar" select="replace($varCode, '.*\.(.*)\..*', '$1')"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="newVar" select="tokenize($varCode, '.')[2]"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($varCode, '.'), '.')"/>
```

Comment: After this, the trimmed string will get stored in varCode only or we need to do some sort of assigning ?

Comment: This returns the trimmed string. If you want it in a variable, use `<xsl:variable name="anotherVar" select="substring-before(substring-after($varCode, '.'), '.')"/>`. Variables in XSLT are immutable.